# Proof of identity for $\pi$: $\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}\cdots$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, pi, infinite-product

While browsing the internet today, I came across the following picture:  [image](full image can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeEvO.jpg) - credit to Цогтгэрэл Гантөмөр)

Now, it would naturally seem we can extend this to an infinite product; specifically, I would guess from this post that we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{ \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}} \cdots}$$

where we define this product formally by
$$\frac{\pi}{3} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{a_n} $$ where $a_n$ is defined by $a_n = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$ with initial value $a_0 = \sqrt{3}.$

However, I have never seen this expression for $\pi$ in the literature. Given this product comes from a geometric argument bounding the value of $\pi,$ I would fully expect this product to be studied, but I do not know where to look. The most similar product I am aware of is
$$\frac{2}{\pi} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}\cdots$$ namely formula $(65)$ on [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html).

I would imagine that, like this similar looking formula for $\frac{2}{\pi},$ the above product for $\frac{\pi}{3}$ should be the result of evaluating some rational function of trigonometric functions, but how to go about this is not immediately clear to me.

**Is anyone aware of an existing proof or refutation of this product in the literature, or else can provide one?**

---

*Edit 1:* I have numerically checked this with the following quick and dirty Javascript code, which seems to imply convergence is decently rapid:

```
a = Math.sqrt(3);
piEstimate = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  a = Math.sqrt(2 + a);
  piEstimate *= 2/a;
}
console.log(3 * piEstimate)
```

Comment: @YuiToCheng: I hadn't encountered that kind of conflict (prioritizing "Hot Network Question" status over MathJax-formatted titles) before ... I guess it makes sense, although I personally don't care much for downgrading title quality for the sake of "network exposure". Someday —perhaps today of all days— someone's going to do [a site search for "formula for pi"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=formula+for+pi) and see yet another unhelpfully-generic title among countless others. Oh, well ...

Comment: Let me solve the dilemma of quality vs. HNQ by making sure the question is not added to the HNQ again. Now we can focus on quality.

Comment: The one of the revision comments about tags, there *is* a point in having lesser-watched tags. Because otherwise you might as well merge all tags into "mathematics". Not *everything* is about increasing the exposure of your question.

Comment: Searchability comes from *well written posts* not from "oversimplified titles". This is a mathematics website, its content will invariably contain mathematics. Titles are useful for browsing, *after* searching, and they should reflect the content of the question to the best ability possible, regardless to MathJax or not being used. As for tags, there is a limit of 5 tags per question. If you have only 2, and you "draw the line", then you're using tags wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The nested square roots suggest Viète's formula and one way that formula can be derived, Euler's product identity for the sinc function:
$$\frac{\sin x}x=\cos\frac x2\cos\frac x4\cos\frac x8\dots$$
Viète's formula is obtained by substituting $x=\frac\pi2$. We use $x=\frac\pi3$ instead:
$$\frac{\sin\pi/3}{\pi/3}=\cos\frac\pi6\cos\frac\pi{12}\cos\frac\pi{24}\dots$$
$$\frac{\sqrt3/2}{\pi/3}=\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos\frac\pi{12}\cos\frac\pi{24}\dots$$
$$\frac3\pi=\cos\frac\pi{12}\cos\frac\pi{24}\dots$$
By applying the half-angle formula $\cos\frac x2=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}2}=\frac{\sqrt{2+2\cos x}}2$ repeatedly we get
$$\cos\frac\pi{12}=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}2$$
$$\cos\frac\pi{24}=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}}2$$
and so on, yielding
$$\frac3\pi=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}}2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}}}2\cdots$$
and from there the desired expression for $\pi$.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly the sort of answer I expected to exist but couldn't easily figure out myself.